# How can I end Beta (Early Access/Open Track) in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Is it possible to end an app in beta (also known as open track or early access)? I currently have my app in internal app sharing, and decided to release it to Alpha - but noticed no differences, so tried to release it to Beta. But after reading supporting documentation which explains the difference between Alpha and Beta, I discovered I don't actually want to be in Beta yet.

There's no clear indications anywhere to say I can remove it, I've removed testers on the Beta release and even done a new release with no APK. But it's still accessible on the Google Play Store.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this genuinely by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by design, what you can do is, go to **Manage country availability** and uncheck all countries, then it won't be available to

Comment: I'm sure there must be some good reason for that? If I follow your suggestion, changing the availability in the beta release, to unavailable in all regions, it doesn't let me save it?

Comment: It is because you have to select at least one country, you can do a little hack by choosing a country where you don't have any testers.Then you would be able to save it.

Comment: What's the purpose for the testers part in beta? Because I can still view and install my app from a device which has no association to the app. Also, looking at country availability it has (Production) next to the UK - which might explain something. But I have no production releases, so I don't know why it says that.

Comment: Just increase your version code and release it to alpha.

Comment: If it is in beta/alpha, you can only install it on devices where tester's account is used in google play.

Comment: The last thing I did before trying your suggestion, was uploaded a new build version to Internal Testing - though the Early Access release is the only app I see. Even if I use the internal opt-in URL for Internal App Testing.

Comment: You would see it if you are logged in with tester account on google play.

Comment: It honestly doesn't matter what I try, all I ever see is the Early Access version which is what I want to remove. I've tried a google account in the internal testing, another google account which is not in the internal testing. I've tried incognito mode on the browse, I've tried multiple Android versions all with different accounts. Does not matter what I do, Early Access is all I see.

Comment: Then make sure you haven't released it to production, that's the only case which is possible.

Comment: I've doubled checked App releases, and my Production Track is empty, it's never had any interaction before. So definitely not in production.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207596/discussion-between-abubakar-and-mattvon).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after playing around with settings, it was literally down to my expectations for things to happen almost instantly similar to TestFlight on iOS. Google can take up to 3 hours to process an update, and I wasn't aware of this.

If anyone else has a similar issue - wait. But the conversation with Abubakar are useful ways to hide the app, but it won't be instant, so be patient.

Answer (score 0):

There is option to remove testers in the Beta Manage page. Just Expand manage testers and click on Remove testers button.